# Images not showing properly in email when site is password protected

Tags: .htaccess, magento-1.9, password-protection

My Magento development website is password protected through .htaccess and .htpasswd. I have share via email feature in my website. On click of product share an email is sent with image of product.

Email is sent no issues in this but issue is images are not shown in the email. If i remove password protect rule from .htaccess file and share the product, image is seen properly in the email with out an issue.

I want to display image in the email when my site having password protect rule in the .htaccess

Comment: That is exactly what should happen. You have password protected the website which includes assets. Either put assets on a separate URL/CDN or in your .htaccess rules exclude your assets folder from the Basic Auth rule.

Comment: how can i do this ? please help me

Comment: You have't posted any of your htaccess rules or code to the question